# How to store modifications without changing the original DB record

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema, database-schema

I'm building an app in which users can create entities that are stored in my Entity table with some caracteristics like "space_below" and "width". Users can also create their own groups of entities by choosing amongst everybody's entities. Once they picked someone else's entity, I want them to be able to modify some caracteristics like the "width" and save these modifications for their own group. What would be to best way to do that in my DB?

**First approach**
Each time a user do a modification, create a new record (almost a duplicate) in the Entity table and then only refer to this new entity from the group where it was change.

In this case, I would need to add a column to my Entity table to differentiate original entites from copied entites.

**Second approach**
In any scenario, I will have a junction table between the Group table and the Entity table. In this junction table, I could add a "modification" column in which I store a JSON with the modifications. Something like `{ space_below: '8', width: '200' }`. If there is no modficiation, the value of the column will be null.

I think I prefer the second approach since the first one involves a lot of duplicated data in the Entity table, but might not be aware of other implications.

Comment: SO is not an appropriate forum for general design discussions like this. It's for specific questions about code you've written, which can have concrete, "correct" answers.

Comment: What are the schema and database-schema tags for then?

Comment: Questions about problems you're having with a database schema.